# Opening bootstrap modal view in Django for editing a post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning basic Django development and am creating a simple blog app with several posts that I create. My home page includes this code that iterates through all posts and displays them.

```
{% for post in all_posts %}
    <div class="post-card">
      {{post.title}}
      {{post.description}}
      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#postEditModal">
        Edit Post
      </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I have a #postEditModal which links to the Bootstrap data-target method and shows the following

```
<div id=#postEditModal class="modal fade" style="overflow: scroll;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    {{editpostform}}
</div>
```

**My goal** is to be able to click on the "Edit Post" link for each individual post, which should redirect to the slug for the post and open the modal all on top of the same page, and from there I should be able to edit the post using my `{{editpostform}}`. Clicking outside of the modal area should revert back to the same page.

I have tried many things like `post.get_absolute_url` and `{% url 'single_post' post.id %}`, but nothing so far has worked properly. I am assuming there is some level of Javascript/AJAX involved but I am not sure where to start with that.

Comment: why do you want to redirect to a different url? You can just capture the post details in the modal form when user clicks Edit Post and post the form to the view where you can make updates.

Comment: The reason that I'd like to redirect to the specific post url is because eventually I'd like to add a "detail modal" view in which I can view my full blog post within the modal and then exit. The Pinterest modal view simulates the functionality that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating several `modals` with the same `id`, and all your links point (`data-target`) to the same modal, which is not unique.

An easy solution is to add the post ID to the modal and the link. Try this:

```
<div id="#postEditModal{{ post.id }}" class="modal fade" style="overflow: scroll;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    {{editpostform}}
</div>
```

And modify the links like this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#postEditModal{{ post.id }}">Edit Post</a>
```

Comment: Adding the #postEditModal{{post.id}} breaks the link for me. Without the {{post.id}} the modal opens just fine.

Comment: But in that case, you are opening an empty form, arent you? If what you want is edit each post, you need to load the modal using ajax, and populate the form with select post data.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or do you know how I would start going about loading the modal using Ajax and populating the form with the individual post information? I also want to have a "detail view" and want to show post.title and post.description. This is why I thought it'd be easier to redirect to the individual post slug.

Comment: According to the bootstrap [modal documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options), bootstrap's native support for ajax loading is deprecated, so you have to use jquery `load()` method.